# Add responsive image to a website split into 4 responsive boxes

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make a website that would consist of 4 boxes each 50% height and width. I found code that does that, but now I struggle to add images into each box. I want each of the four divs to have a different image, and they should scale according to window size. Any help is appreciated.

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/OJRdyRR

Here's what I would like to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJy1R.jpg

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="column"><img src="https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0846297992_16.jpg"></div>
<div class="column">IMG 2</div>
<div class="column">IMG 3</div>
<div class="column">IMG 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
.column {
  height: 25%;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .column {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}


/* general styles */
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #000;
  /*margin-bottom: 70px;*/
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  /*border: 1px solid #666;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column:nth-child(1) {
  background: #5c9;
}
.column:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fb0;
}
.column:nth-child(3) {
  background: #39f;
}
.column:nth-child(4) {
  background: #f33;
}

main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify and simplify your issue a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve but I'd do it with by setting `object-fit: contain` on images. I also changed a bit the way (css) you're defining the divs.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  height: 50vh;  
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.column:nth-child(1) {
  background: #5c9;
}

.column:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fb0;
}

.column:nth-child(3) {
  background: #39f;
}

.column:nth-child(4) {
  background: #f33;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"><img src="https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0846297992_16.jpg"></div>
  <div class="column">IMG 2</div>
  <div class="column">IMG 3</div>
  <div class="column">IMG 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, I think I didn't express it properly, sorry! this is what I want: https://i.imgur.com/7CR7sW8.jpg so each box has an image inside it and it scales up and down depending on the screen / browser size - i think in your example the image is stretched to max width, but bits of it are not visible - I want the whole square to be visible at all times.

ALSO I've just realised that those boxes are stacking up instead of forming this grid. Im a bit lost now actually :/

Comment: In that case you should rather set `contain` on `object-fit`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Your column img class is set to 100% width and height. I set the height to 50% and the width to auto so it detects the image size and displays it noramlly.
And i simply removed the "object-fit: cover;".

If you change your .colum img {} to the following it should be exactly what you want.

```
.column img {
  height: 50%;
  width: auto;
 }
```

I added a snippet so you can see it working.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  height: 50vh;  
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column img {
  height: 50%;
  width: auto;
}

.column:nth-child(1) {
  background: #5c9;
}

.column:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fb0;
}

.column:nth-child(3) {
  background: #39f;
}

.column:nth-child(4) {
  background: #f33;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="column"><img src="https://f4.bcbits.com/img/a0846297992_16.jpg"></div>
<div class="column">IMG 2</div>
<div class="column">IMG 3</div>
<div class="column">IMG 4</div>
</div>
```